# How can I print an octave plot to a .pdf file from the windows command line?

Tags: cmd, command-line, octave

I'm trying to pass some data to octave by writing to the windows command line from python in one single line, but I am getting an error.
I found some sample code at https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.0/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html and I made a one line variation of it to suit my needs:

```
f=figure('Visible','off');plot([1,2,3,4]);pause(1);print(f,"myplot.pdf","-dpdflatexstandalone");
```

when I run this one line in octave itself, it works flawlessly, and I can find a file named myplot-inc.pdf in the octave folder (it will be in a different location in the future once i actually get the code to work). However, when I run it from command line using

```
octave --silent --persist --eval f=figure('Visible','off');plot([1,2,3,4]);pause(1);print(f,"myplot.pdf","-dpdflatexstandalone");
```

it gives this error:

```
error: 'test_plot' undefined near line 1 column 60
```

I would like to eventually run it without the --persist option, possibly even using -W to prevent octave from opening, if at all possible. For now, how can I make this code work from the command line in the same way it works in octave?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this happened fairly quickly. since I'm running from command line, I have to use single quotes around 'myplot.pdf' and '-dpdflatexstandalone' instead of double quotes.